# HTML form PHP post not working

Tags: php, html, forms, post, form-submit

I'm writing a little website for myself and I'm having trouble with what seems like a simple line of code:

```
form action="send.php" method="post"
```

Furthermore, even a simple line like `form action="http://www.google.com">` isn't working.  Here is my code:

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>  
            AnonMail!  
        </title>  
    </head>  
    <body style="font-family:'Tahoma';>  
        <form action="send.php" method="post">  
            <label for="from">From:  </label><input type="text" name="from" id="from"></input></br>  
            <label for="to">To:  </label><input type="text" name="to" id="to"></input></br>  
            <label for="subj">Subject:  </label><input type="text" name="subj" id="subj"></input></br>  
            <textarea rows=10 cols=100 name="message"></textarea></br>  
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>  
        </form>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: What does your send.php script file look like?
Btw, you can't use google.com as your action. It sounds like your send.php file must be set up incorrectly.

Comment: How's about posting your send.php code? Also, you have some just plain bad html there. it's <br />, not </br> and in html5 just <br>. You have no "value" attributes in your form elements. Your form has no ID, which sort of doesn't matter but it;s supposed to. and if it is xhtml it should have at least one fieldset in there to be "valid". also, input is self closing. get rid of the </input> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a form that should work:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<p><b>Your Name:</b> <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br />
<b>Subject:</b> <input type="text" name="subject" /><br />
<b>E-mail:</b> <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Website: <input type="text" name="website"></p>   
<p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you're still having troubles: http://myphpform.com/php-form-not-working.php

Answer (score 6):

The error starts with your body tag.
You have not closed your double quotes in the style tag of your body.
Just close it properly and then run it.
I think that is only the problem.

Answer (score -1):

browsers show warnings when your action refers to an external source. Some browsers do not post form at all. This is unsafe for users.